# How to remove an element from an array in ReactJS Redux state, when a condition is true?

Tags: reactjs, redux, rxjs, state

Basically I have a table with rows of items. These rows have 4 cells with text in. You can delete cells/text from the rows from right -> left. So "1 2 3 4" can be "1 2 3 -" for example, if you delete cells/text from right -> left.

Here's my reducer code in which I'll have to delete the entire row as well, as the "1" in the above example is deleted as well. It's just so that I don't want a row visible with "- - - -" for example, it can just delete the entire row by that point. So here's my code:

```
case DELETE_SITE: {
      return {
        ...state,
        siteRows: state.siteRows.map((s) => {
          if (s.siteLevel2Id && s.siteLevel2Id == action.payload.id) 
            //return {...s, siteLevel2Id: null, siteLevel2Name: null, canDeleteLevel2: null};
            return state.siteRows.slice(0, 1);
          if (s.siteLevel3Id && s.siteLevel3Id == action.payload.id) 
            return {...s, siteLevel3Id: null, siteLevel3Name: null, canDeleteLevel3: null};
          if (s.siteLevel4Id && s.siteLevel4Id == action.payload.id) 
            return {...s, siteLevel4Id: null, siteLevel4Name: null, canDeleteLevel4: null};
          if (s.siteLevel5Id && s.siteLevel5Id == action.payload.id) 
            return {...s, siteLevel5Id: null, siteLevel5Name: null, canDeleteLevel5: null};
          return s;
         }),
      }
    }
```

As you can see, as long as 3, 2 are deleted, 1 will still be filled in and it will look like this "1 - - -". Now if we delete the "1" as well, here named "siteLevel2...", it would show "- - - -" but I just want to remove the entire row from "state.siteRows".

I've tried the line that's in comment right now, but it just adds a "null" value to the array that is "siteRows", like this: {null, [siteRow1]} so it crashes in my screen because it's trying to do things like "null.id".

I've tried on the second line splicing the first element from the array (removing it) but it doesn't seem to work either.

Can anyone help me with this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following:

```js
const DELETE_SITE = 'DELETE_SITE';
const testReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case DELETE_SITE: {
      const keys = [
        ['siteLevel2Id', 2],
        ['siteLevel3Id', 3],
        ['siteLevel4Id', 4],
        ['siteLevel5Id', 5],
      ];
      const reset = (num, item) => ({
        ...item,
        [`siteLevel${num}Id`]: null,
        [`siteLevel${num}Name`]: null,
        [`canDeleteLevel${num}`]: null,
      });
      const recurCheck = (id) => (row) => {
        const recur = (index) => {
          const [currentKey, num] = keys[index];
          //nothing to do, no match
          if (index >= keys.length - 1) {
            return row;
          }
          //row siteLevelNId matches id, reset this row
          if (row[currentKey] && row[currentKey] == id) {
            return reset(num, row);
          }
          //recur try the next index
          return recur(index + 1);
        };
        return recur(0);
      };
      return {
        ...state,
        siteRows: state.siteRows
          .map(recurCheck(action.payload?.id))
          //if any of these keys return true
          //  do not remove this row
          .filter((row) => keys.some(([key]) => row[key])),
      };
    }
    default: {
      return state;
    }
  }
};
console.log(
  'no rows',
  testReducer(
    { siteRows: [] },
    { type: DELETE_SITE, payload: { id: 1 } }
  ).siteRows
);
const createItem = (num) => ({
  [`siteLevel${num}Id`]: num,
  [`siteLevel${num}Name`]: num,
  [`canDeleteLevel${num}`]: num,
});
console.log(
  'id 3',
  testReducer(
    { siteRows: [createItem(3)] },
    { type: DELETE_SITE, payload: { id: 3 } }
  ).siteRows
);
console.log(
  'id 2',
  testReducer(
    { siteRows: [{ ...createItem(2), siteLevel3Id: 3 }] },
    { type: DELETE_SITE, payload: { id: 2 } }
  ).siteRows
);
```

I tried to clean up repeating logic but you could leave it as is, the  thing that solves your problem is the filter function after the map function.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! When I execute your example code, I still get some React errors it seems and it crashes. These are the errors I get: "Failed prop type: Invalid prop `children` supplied to `ForwardRef(Alert)`, expected a ReactNode." && "Objects are not valid as a React child (found: TypeError: undefined is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead." && Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application..." Any ideas?

Comment: I must say, I added some console.logs and they are all triggered in "recurCheck" etc so it loops through the code, no problem. But then I guess when it tries to set the "siteRows" property or execute the filter, that's when it throws the errors?

Comment: I've fixed it by modifying your code somewhat. I've changed the place where you do the "index" check (index >= ...) to now be happening right before the "recur(index +1)" line. I also added the index+1 before my check and not in the "recur(index +1)" line. Then it works :) thank you for your help!

Comment: @Tempuslight I didn't test it but you are right, should be `if (index >= keys.length - 1) {`, no other changes needed. I added a testable snippet.